# How can just set write permission (unix chmod 0777) to a folder and git commit it in windows?

Tags: windows, git, unix

I use `git` in `windows`.

I know for set executeable file and commit it, can use this:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x <file>
```

But now, How can just set read and write permission (unix chmod 0777) to a folder and git commit it in windows?!

And also I try `git config core.filemode true` and `chmod 077 <folder>` in `Cygwin` but does not work.

Note that I am talking about folder and not file permissions.

Comment: So you want read and write? Or just write?

Comment: @cricket_007 read and write (no executable)

Comment: Okay... I think you misunderstand directory file permissions. You might want to read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18098/148686

Comment: Folders are never executable.  Octal 1 on a directory permission is the *search* bit.  You probably don't want to remove it - but even if you did, again, Git cannot store that permission.

Comment: @EdwardThomson do you thinks if I set +x for a folder for upload files by user in here, that's not have security bug?

Comment: You cannot set `+x` for a folder because, again, git does not store the permissions for folders, only for files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.  Git does not store the complete permissions for files, it only stores whether a file is executable or not.  For folders, it stores no permissions at all.

Your `umask` will influence the permissions that are used when folders are created on your local machine, but this is not something that can be committed to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Since windows does not use the permissions bit(s) it has no effect under windows.

One way to "force" git to track those changes is to work with the **git Bash** which will cause git to work in a **Unix like** environment and due to that you will be able to track changes made to the file permissions.

---

#### Here is a working demo for you

[image]

Comment: Agreed, if you are on unix its build in but the question was tagged with windows so i displayed in bash.

Comment: No my point is that you can run it from cmd.exe, you don't need to run Git Bash.

Comment: And what if you installed git and not added it to the path?